# Why is the wedge product of a 1-form and itself $0$?

Tags: calculus, exterior-algebra

Why is the wedge product of a 1-form and itself $0$?
Why doesn't this apply to 2-forms?

Comment: In its current form, this question lacks context and therefore may be closed. Please consider improving your question.

Comment: The question seems kind of self-explanatory -- I don't see what more context would be necessary.

Comment: @William Well, consider the tags of the question. The first tag is "calculus". This would suggest that one is talking about de Rham forms, I guess? But the second tag is "exterior-algebra". So are we talking about exterior algebras (the assumption that the answer used), maybe? Which is it? This is the kind of vagueness that would be eliminated by a tiny bit of context. It's not asking much! Even a link to Wikipedia would be a good start!

Comment: Oh to be fair I didn't look at the tags, but I can see now how they would be misleading. I had just assumed it was talking about differential forms but hadn't really thought through the terminological ambiguity.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Would the difference in context (purely differential vs. purely algebraic) change anything? No, the proof would be the same: $(\alpha \wedge \alpha) (u, v) = \frac 1 2 (\alpha (u) \alpha (v) - \alpha (v) \alpha (u)) = 0$. After all, the exterior differential algebra *is* an exterior algebra. Let's not be picky just because we can.

Comment: @AlexM. Did you read Travis's answer? Try to make sense of it assuming that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differential forms; it doesn't. What you've written isn't completely rigorous either, since differential forms are *sections* of the exterior algebra on the cotangent *bundle* (not space)... The thing you've written only holds locally. So you see, knowing whether we're talking about a plain exterior algebra or differential forms matters. And in any case, there *are* standards for a minimum amount of context, regardless of whether the question is comprehensible.

Comment: @AlexM. And hey, maybe it's a graded manifold, in which case the 1-form could have even degree and not square to zero! Or maybe we're working in characteristic 2, and then [it depends on the precise definition of the exterior algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/291083/10014). Who knows, the question doesn't say.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I totally understand your point about the context, I just tend to be on the permissive side. Anyway, what I've written holds both on a vector space, and for global sections on a manifold. I don't use trivializations anywhere, think of $\alpha, u, v$ as being a global $1$-form and two vector fields. That definition of the wedge product is global, too. I agree about supermanifolds and characteristic $2$, but I feel that your argument is a bit stretched.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By definition, the wedge product of $1$-forms $\alpha, \beta$ is $$\alpha \wedge \beta = \alpha \otimes \beta - \beta \otimes \alpha .$$ When $\beta = \alpha$, this is zero.

The wedge product of $2$-forms has a different formula, so this conclusion does not apply in that case. Indeed, for any finite-dimensional vector space $\Bbb V$ of dimension $\geq 4$ (and whose underlying field has characteristic not $2$), fix a cobasis $(e^a)$ of $\Bbb V$; the $2$-form $$\omega := e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^3 \wedge e^4$$ satisfies $\omega \wedge \omega = 2 e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^4 \neq 0$. A useful fact is that a $2$-form $\zeta$ satisfies $\zeta \wedge \zeta = 0$ iff $\zeta$ is decomposable, that is, if it can be written as $\zeta = \alpha \wedge \beta$ for some $1$-forms $\alpha, \beta$ (this assertion again requires that $\operatorname{char} \Bbb F \neq 2$).

On a vector space of dimension $<4$ the wedge product of any form with itself is zero.